# Running embedded R gives a NameError

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm a python newbie trying to follow along with this great blog on finding seasonal customers:

[Python Code for Identifying Seasonal Customers](https://datamovesme.com/2018/07/01/seasonality-python-code)

However, I am stuck on one of the last steps. The code is this:

```
customerTS = stats.ts(dataForOwner.SENDS.astype(int),
        start=base.c(startYear,startMonth),
        end=base.c(endYear, endMonth),
        frequency=12)
```

I get this error: `NameError: name 'dataForOwner' is not defined`

*Edit* I should add that this last line is also in the code block but I still get error without including:

```
customerTS = stats.ts(dataForOwner.SENDS.astype(int),
        start=base.c(startYear,startMonth),
        end=base.c(endYear, endMonth),
        frequency=12)
r.assign('customerTS', customerTS)
```

I have googled quite a bit and having no luck getting it to work.

Comment: dataForOwner looks like a defined function. I mean it is not preloaded with python. That's what happen with some tutorials, they assume you will know how to define  some basic or non basic that looks obvious to them. You need to define that function on your own.

Comment: It appears to be a typo: `dataForOwner` should be `dataForCustomer`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried that as well but got "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'SENDS'

Comment: @herc01 should I be able to do that with the information I have or need to ask the blog writer? Thx!

Comment: @DavidSquires I can't seem to find that function defined anywhere on the page, before the code you are referring. Maybe, you should send a message to the blogger, she is missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NameError: name 'dataForOwner' is not defined
```

Is raised by Python itself to indicate it is unable to find an object called `dataForOWner` in the current context. To experience it yourself, just start a new Python terminal and type `x` (a variable name that does not exist).

The issue is either with the blog your refer to (the definition of `dataForOwner` is missing) or with that definition forgotten by a user trying to reproduce that blog.

Comment: I messaged the blog owner to confirm but I believe this is correct. I switched it to dataForCustomer, and also realized SENDS was a column in the dataframe instead of usage, the code then ran. I wish i could give @john Zwinck credit too